# Flash on IE10 - scanHardware gives two of the same camera

Tags: flash, actionscript, webcam, internet-explorer-10

I'm working on an interface that allows users to view the webcams available on their system, and select one for later use. In the instance that users realize they don't have the webcam they want plugged in, they are provided with a button to "Refresh Cameras". This calls Flash's utility function: `flash.media.scanHardware`, retrieving a new set of `Camera.names`. In Internet Explorer 7-9, and Firefox, this works great (on Chrome, we found we needed to use a workaround). However, we find that on Internet Explorer 10, the behavior gets kind of weird. `Camera.names` shows two camera names, which are both the same. Attempting to retrieve them breaks our previous "connect to Video" code, too.

I'm using Flash Builder to build this app in Flex, and targetting Flash Player 10.1.

Comment: Well, as I see it you can either try to find out what is causing this, or just check if any item you add to "the list of available devices" is the same as some other device already registered, and in that case don't add it :)

Comment: I've inspected the AS Camera api to the level I can; at the root level, it's giving me duplicate cameras. If I don't add the camera, then users will think that their camera isn't working, and will frustratedly decide they need a new one. (Their camera does work; but the only way flash will recognize it is if they refresh the page. Refreshing isn't a very preferable option. Also, some cameras quite genuinely have the same name.)